# How to get value of checkbox in capybara?

Tags: automation, cucumber, capybara

i have code html like this

`<input type="checkbox" class="class-of-checkbox" value="facebook">`

how to get the value (`facebook`) ?

Comment: isn't `find(#class-of-checkbox).value` working for you? which language are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to uniquely find the element and then call `value` on it.  How you find the element uniquely can be highly dependent on the structure of the rest of the page, but based on just the single element HTML you've provided (and you not actually knowing what the value already is) either of the following could be a starting place

```
find('.class-of-checkbox').value
find_field(type: 'checkbox', class: 'class-of-checkbox').value
```

If you just want to verify the value of an element with an expectation then you could do (assuming RSpec with cucumber)

```
expect(page).to have_field(type: 'checkbox', with: 'facebook', class: 'class-of-checkbox')  # you can also pass :checked option if you want to verify it is checked - or use have_checked_field/have_unchecked_field
```